# Sort App Shortcuts in OS X System Preferences Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, sorting, system-preferences

I have a long list of custom shortcuts I've created in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts for menu items in Pro Tools. Despite having edited the application's plist file (com.avid.ProTools.plist, which lists the shortcuts shown in system preferences) to sort the shortcuts properly, they still appear in the same random order in the System Preferences UI. Is there any way to get the UI to update and show the sorted list of shortcuts as they are saved in the application's plist file?

Answer (score 0):

No. Those are three different files.
The app saves its' shortcuts to the file `~/Library/Preferences/com.avid.ProTools.plist`.
The macOS saves the shortcut preferences of the predefined shortcuts to the file `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist`, 
and the ones you manually defined in the `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`

If you strive to backup the manually configured shortcuts, save the two latter files. The .GlobalPreferences.plist will have many more settings that have nothing to do with the Pro Tools.
:)